# Виртуальная клавиатура

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать виртуальную клавиатуру на js наподобие тех, что делают на сайтах для калькуляторов. Например, есть кнопка с цифрой 1, при нажатии на которую цифра 1 добавляется в поле ввода. Аналогично и с буквами.

Меня интересует такой вариант виртуальной клавиатуры, чтобы при нажатии на её кнопку срабатывали те же события, что и при нажатии кнопки на обычной клавиатуре (keypress, keydown), и при этом не терялся фокус с поля ввода.

Подскажите где как это лучше сделать?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вставить в инпут значение? или вызвать собитие?

Comment: А зачем закрыли отвеченный вопрос? :D

Comment: @Visman: формулировка у него очень размытая. «Хочу сделать» — пожалуйста, делайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myinput').on('keypress', function() {
    $('#action').fadeIn(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    });
  });

  $('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
    var Paste = $(this).data('paste');
    $('#myinput').val($('#myinput').val() + Paste).trigger('keypress');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myinput">
<button class="mybutton" data-paste="1">1</button>
<button class="mybutton" data-paste="2">2</button>
<button class="mybutton" data-paste="3">3</button>
<hr>
<span id="action" style="display:none">Key press</span>
```